# How to make a 'Red Stoplight' button appear in table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m running scripts that poll 4 enclosures in a datacenter for health status (power, cooling..etc). The data is stored in an array and then is piped over to html for a clean look. Eventually I’d like to get to a dashboard possibly. For now I would like a ‘Red Stoplight’ button to appear if the poll is anything but Ok (see code) in the cell instead of the string OK. Is this even possible? Thanks!

Here is my code for this project:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<script>
function ShowHide(body_id){ 
var TBody 

TBody = document.getElementById(body_id); 

if(!TBody) return true; 

if (TBody.style.display=="none") { 
  TBody.style.display="table" 
  } 
else { 
  TBody.style.display="none" 
  } 

return true; 
} 
</script>
<html><head><title>VCE Daily Battle Rhythm Report</title>
        <META http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html; charset=windows-1252'>

        <style type="text/css">

        TABLE       {
                        TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed;
                        FONT-SIZE: 100%; 
                        WIDTH: 100%;                
                    }
        *
                    {
                        margin:0
                    }

        .pageholder {
                        margin: 0px auto;
                    }

        td              {
                        VERTICAL-ALIGN: TOP; 
                        FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma;
                    }

        th          {
                        VERTICAL-ALIGN: TOP; 
                        COLOR: #018AC0; 
                        TEXT-ALIGN: left;
                    }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body margin-left: 4pt; margin-right: 4pt; margin-top: 6pt;>
<div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px; font-weight:bolder; background-color:#FFFFFF;"><center>
<p class="accent">
<div class="MainTitle">Daily Enclosure Report</div>
<div class="SubTitle">Report created on 02/19/2016 07:07:23</div>
<div class="SubTitle">Server Enclosures Checked</div>
<br/>
</p>
</center></div>


        <div style="
    BORDER-RIGHT: medium none; 
    BORDER-TOP: medium none; 
    DISPLAY: block; 
    BACKGROUND: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%; 
    MARGIN-BOTTOM: -1px; 
    FONT: 100%/8px Tahoma; 
    MARGIN-LEFT: 43px; 
    BORDER-LEFT: medium none; 
    COLOR: #ffffff; 
    MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px; 
    PADDING-TOP: 4px; 
    BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; 
    POSITION: relative
"></div>        <h2 onclick="ShowHide('9')" style="
    BORDER-RIGHT: #bbbbbb 1px solid;
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    BORDER-TOP: #bbbbbb 1px solid;
    DISPLAY: block;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
    FONT-SIZE: 8pt;
    MARGIN-BOTTOM: -1px;
    MARGIN-LEFT: AUTO;
    BORDER-LEFT: #bbbbbb 1px solid;
    COLOR: #000000;
    MARGIN-RIGHT: AUTO;
    PADDING-TOP: 4px;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #bbbbbb 1px solid;
    FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma;
    POSITION: relative;
    HEIGHT: 2.25em;
    WIDTH: 95%;
    TEXT-INDENT: 10px;
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #B8B8B8;
">Data Center Enclosures: 4</h2>        <div style="
    BORDER-RIGHT: #bbbbbb 1px solid;
    BORDER-TOP: #bbbbbb 1px solid;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    FONT-SIZE: 8pt;
    MARGIN-BOTTOM: -1px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px;
    MARGIN-LEFT: AUTO;
    BORDER-LEFT: #bbbbbb 1px solid;
    WIDTH: 95%;
    COLOR: #000000;
    MARGIN-RIGHT: AUTO;
    PADDING-TOP: 4px;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #bbbbbb 1px solid;
    FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma;
    POSITION: relative;
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f9f9f9
"><TABLE id="9"><style>tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #E5E5E5; TABLE-LAYOUT: Fixed; FONT-SIZE: 100%; WIDTH: 100%;}</style>
<colgroup>
<col/><col/>
<col/><col/>
</colgroup> 
<tr><th style= "COLOR: #2E9AFE; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Name</th>
<th style= "COLOR: #2E9AFE; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Status</th>
<th style= "COLOR: #2E9AFE; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">PowerStatus</th>
<th style= "COLOR: #2E9AFE; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">CoolingStatus</th>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Enclosure: 1 </td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Enclosure: 2 </td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td></tr> 
<tr>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Enclosure: 3 </td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td></tr>
<tr>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Enclosure: 4 </td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
</tr> 
</table>    
</DIV>
    <div style="
    BORDER-RIGHT: medium none; 
    BORDER-TOP: medium none; 
    DISPLAY: block; 
    BACKGROUND: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%; 
    MARGIN-BOTTOM: -1px; 
    FONT: 100%/8px Tahoma; 
    MARGIN-LEFT: 43px; 
    BORDER-LEFT: medium none; 
    COLOR: #ffffff; 
    MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px; 
    PADDING-TOP: 4px; 
    BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; 
    POSITION: relative"></div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you want to do is definitely possible. Do you have control over the HTML? CSS? JS? Avoiding inline styles would be a really good start. FYI: You have this tagged for HTML5 you are using a frameset doctype (which is HTML4).

Comment: Save yourself a headache and get rid of the inline styles and makes them classes. So when you need to update a size you are not doing in 20 places, just one. If you do not control that, sorry you have to inherit that mess. So you would need to have some JavaScript that looks at the table and looks for a string other than ok and set a style on that row.

Comment: Include the red circle in each cell and default it to display:none. Then , you simply need to change it to display:inline based on your criteria. Also, the script tag should not be anywhere but INSIDE the head or the body. You have it prior to the head.

Comment: I have full control of this project. This is the biggest project I've started and definitely the most complex. Will definitely go with stylesheet and classes but just wanted to get this out for assistance first and the tag is an errant click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over td's and replace OK with a button:

```js
var td = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('td'));
td.forEach(function(td) {
  if (td.innerHTML == 'OK') {
    td.innerHTML = '<button class="red_stoplight"></button>';
  }
});
```

```css
.red_stoplight {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<TABLE id="9"><style>tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #E5E5E5; TABLE-LAYOUT: Fixed; FONT-SIZE: 100%; WIDTH: 100%;}</style>
<colgroup>
<col/><col/>
<col/><col/>
</colgroup> 
<tr><th style= "COLOR: #2E9AFE; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Name</th>
<th style= "COLOR: #2E9AFE; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Status</th>
<th style= "COLOR: #2E9AFE; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">PowerStatus</th>
<th style= "COLOR: #2E9AFE; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">CoolingStatus</th>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Enclosure: 1 </td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Enclosure: 2 </td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td></tr> 
<tr>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Enclosure: 3 </td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td></tr>
<tr>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">Enclosure: 4 </td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
<td style= "FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;">OK</td>
</tr> 
</TABLE>
```

Comment: I think this will work! My JS skills are merely slightly above novice so there is plenty of room to improve. Hopefully when I'm able to establish even more metrics in the poll I'll be able to show several different button colors. My ultimate objective is to have a simple dashboard that shows these statuses versus the html/text/css buttons.  Thanks!

Comment: But, for accessibility, you should put a _word_ inside the button too, for example `OK` in a green button, `ERR` in a red button ... [Red/Green color blindness](https://nei.nih.gov/health/color_blindness/facts_about#5) occurs in 7-10% of males so displaying status by using only color is lost for a significant population.

Comment: I was thinking about that after running this. When I poll the enclosures they actually report degraded as a status that I feel could be represented by amber stoplight. Having a red, green or amber indicator doesn't give me 100% status. So if the status comes back degraded how can I add amber button and maintain text?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways - inserting images or using background images or creating rectangles with a border-radius like so:

```
.round {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.round.inactive {
  display: none;
}
```

See here: https://jsbin.com/suxazonuyi/1/edit?html,output

All you got to do is set class `round` on all stoplight elements and set or take away class `inactive`:

```
    <li onclick="ShowHide('first')"><span id="first" class="round"></span></li>
```